# Why can't you access "deeper" object variables when said object variable is used in a string?

Tags: php

What I mean is, while you can do something like this:

```
$foo = "Yo dawg I herd you like $bar->baz";
```

This:

```
$foo = "Yo dawg I herd you like $bar->baz->qux";
```

Results in the following error:

```
"Object of class * could not be converted to string"
```

The cleanest way around it seems to be something like:

```
$baz = $bar->baz;

$foo = "Yo dawg I herd you like $baz->qux";
```

So why doesn't it work and is there is a better solution?

NOTICE:

I know some people prefer to have their variables outside of their strings but this is not the venue to talk about such preferences and does not address the question I'm asking so I'd appreciate if you leave such subjective sentiments out of this. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I think this applies also for using 'variable variables in instances:   `$inst1->$inst2->attribute` doesn't work, but `$i2_att=$inst2->attribute;   $inst1->$i2_att;` does work well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because a simple interpolation (see description in http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - "Variable parsing" section) explicitly was designed to only interpolate embedded "variable, an array value, or an object property in a string".

Please note that it's designed to interpolate "an object property", NOT an "arbitrary expression". To do the latter, your parser would need to do a MUCH MUCH harder jobs when parsing strings.

For the arbitrary expression, you need to use complex (curly) syntax introduced in PHP4 by enclosing said expression in curly braces: `{$bar->baz->qux}` within the string.

Comment: Because some people just can't handle the truth

Answer (score 12):

```
$foo = "Yo dawg I herd you like {$bar->baz->qux}";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

The only *why* I can give you is that the designers chose to implement it this way. For instance, you can't include a function return value in the braces. This is just a design choice.

Comment: I'm curious as to why one needs the brackets. Also, I don't even know what this is called so I'm not sure where to find documentation on it. If you could supply a link (or quote it in this answer) that would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: @Fake - see my answer for both the documentation link and "why"

Comment: @webbiedave: Just a heads up, I upvoted both answers but DVK answered in full first so I marked his answer as accepted. Also, I'm pretty sure whoever downvoted you did so because you didn't explain why. They probably didn't check back to see if you edited your answer.

Comment: @Fake Code: It was downvoted after I added the *why*. No problem though. I was just curious. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @webbiedave: I think we'd all love to know why. I got downvoted as well. Pretty sure DVK did too. Honestly, it's all rather amusing. I'm not offended, would just love to know why. :)

Comment: @Fake Code: lol I guess it'll remain a mystery for both of us.

Comment: Yo dawg. The new hello world.